# I want to integrate my website with AppStore to let customer pay through AppStore

Tags: web, in-app-purchase, app-store

I have an app that allows customer to do in app purchase.
I also have a website and I'd like to let customer to pay on the website through as well, that is, make in app purchase also works on website.
I am not sure if Apple allows their in app purchase work outside of apps, and if it does, how can I do that?

My website is written in Java

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot implement in app purchases outside of the Apple ecosystem.

You would have to take payment another way through your website and then have a server side flag to indicate the user has paid. When the users opens the app check to see if they have paid through a call to the server and unlock the relevant content.

It would work the same for if the user paid through an in app purchase on an apple device - keep a record of this on the server and if they visit the website you can unlock the relevant content.